# JWT signing with private key on PHP

Tags: php

I have and example how to sign JWT key with private key and then decode it with public one on PHP

```
    $privKey = openssl_pkey_new(array('digest_alg' => 'sha256',
        'private_key_bits' => 1024,
        'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA));
    $msg = JWT::encode('abc', $privKey, 'RS256');
    $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($privKey);
    $pubKey = $pubKey['key'];
    $decoded = JWT::decode($msg, $pubKey, array('RS256'));
    $this->assertEquals($decoded, 'abc');
```

but here it generates and then uses generated key on the fly, what if i need to use already generated private and public key? Is it possible/enough to use `file_get_contents`?

**Update**

I found [openssl_pkey_get_private](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php) and [openssl_pkey_get_public](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php) i'll try to use this code with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
$private = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://key', 'keyphrase');
$token = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode('magic', $private, 'RS256');

$public = openssl_pkey_get_public('file://key.pub');
$data = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($token, $public, ['RS256']);
```